# ls listing of Windows dirs in WSL2 is messed up

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I've just installed the Win10 2004 update along with WSL2. When I open a terminal window and run `ls -l`, this is what I see:

[image]

The Windows directories in the listing are highlighted with a green background, and when the path overflows one line, the green is extended to the end of the 2nd line. Is there a way to fix this?

I've tested with both the regular cmd.exe and the new Windows Terminal app, and the problem occurs in both.

Comment: Forgot to mention: distro is Ubuntu 20.04, from the Microsoft Store

Comment: What version of Windows Terminal are you using?  Does installing the latest version from the Microsoft Store fix it?

Comment: @bk2204 this is Terminal 1.0 from the Store, regardless as mentioned, the problem occurs with cmd.exe as well

Answer (score 1):

These `ls` colour settings are stored in the ~/.bashrc file's $LS_COLORS variable. First open the file and go to the end. Search for LS_COLORS and you will find an extensive list of key-value pairs. You have to edit them to the color as you like. List of key value meanings and available color codes from https://linuxhint.com/ls_colors_bash/

> ```
> 31  = red 40  = black background  0   = default colour
> 32  = green   41  = red background    1   = bold
> 33  = orange  42  = green background  4   = underlined
> 34  = blue    43  = orange background 5   = flashing text
> 35  = purple  44  = blue background   7   = reverse field > (exchange foreground and background color)
> 36  = cyan    45  = purple background 8   = concealed (invisible)
> 37  = grey    46  = cyan background   0   = default colour
> 90  = dark grey   47  = grey background   1   = bold
> 91  = light red   100 = dark grey background  
> 92  = light green 101 = light red background  
> 93  = yellow  102 = light green background    
> 94  = light blue  103 = yellow background 
> 95  = light purple    104 = light blue background 
> 96  = turquoise   105 = light purple background   
> 97  = white   106 = turquoise background  
> 107 = white background
> ```

> ```
> no    Global default
> fi    Normal file
> di    Directory
> ln    Symbolic link.
> bd    Block device
> cd    Character device
> or    Symbolic link to a non-existent file
> ex    Executable file
> *.extension   Example, *.mp3
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but I should mention I don't mind the green background. What I'm looking for is a way to have it rendered correctly, ie, not extending to the end of the line